# Should a database table that contains two columns that are foreign keys have a third column which is the primary key?

Tags: database, database-design, primary-key

Should a database table that contains two columns that are foreign keys have a third column which is the primary key?

I am guessing no, since the foreign keys are the primary keys in their own tables, so they will be unique.

I am using MySQL and the following three tables are using the `InnoDB` engine.

```
=======================    =======================
| galleries           |    | images              |
|---------------------|    |---------------------|
| PK | gallery_id     |    | PK | image_id       |
|    | name           |    |    | title          |
|    | description    |    |    | description    |
|    | max_images     |    |    | filename       |
|    | enabled        |    |    | enabled        |
=======================    =======================

========================
| galleries_images     |
|----------------------|
| FK | gallery_id      |
| FK | image_id        |
========================
```

Should I add a PK to the `galleries_images` table?

Comment: +1. Even I am thinking so, but we would need more details. Normally any DB will create a unique Index on the primary key of a table. If your table has only those two foreign keys and no primary key, then I fear the index wont be created(not confirmed, speculating). It then depends on what and how the table is used for.

Comment: Just because the foreign keys map to primary keys in the parent tables, that doesn't mean the combination of foreign keys must be unique.

Comment: WAIT! the only need for a the mapping table is if you're model requires a many to many relationship between gallery and image. If you make the PK Image_ID, it's no longer many-many... just put Gallery_ID in you Image table and be done with this. I don't know what InnoDB is but if it creates garbage like this than one of two things are true, it can't differentiate between many-many and one-many or you can't. This is the problem with starting a database from a physical design. You've not bothered to consider what your relationships are.

Comment: @Stephanie So, the mapping table would be appropriate if individual images could be associated with more than one gallery? That would be many-to-many? But, in my case, since I want the images to be in only one gallery, this is one-to-many and the mapping table is unnecessary?

Comment: RE: managing the order via PHP: this is a case where you may really need to think about concurrency. Could I have two web browsers open  simultaneously? If so, it could be possible that I try to update that order_num from each at the same time. You need to think about how you'll accomplish that. Will you let them rearrange and then write the new order back all at once. Will you write back with each change and only commit at the end? Whatever makes sense for your app, code it with the idea that you could collide and manage it. it's easier to manage in the database. It's built for  concurrency.

Comment: @Stephanie. Thanks. I was planning on having the user lock the table and retrieve the order_num data, edit it on the client side, then update the table and then unlock it. Is this okay?

Comment: @Let, lock rows, then letting the client have a crack at them is typically a bad idea. In your case, in this app, you might not have a lot of other sessions trying to manipulate the same list, right? But if you get in this habit now, large more complex apps will not tolerate such a process. You're allowing those locks to be held indefinitely. Assume the client starts to re-order, you get the locks, he goes to dinner. How long will it take before you know he's disconnected? meanwhile, those rows are locked. The best way to use locks is in and out as fast as possible. Or lock something else.

Comment: @Stephanie: yes - the question changed, leading to the appropriate answers changing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All tables should have a primary key.

It is not necessary to create a new surrogate column to act as primary key though. Taking John's example it would be perfectly acceptable to have a composite primary key with the 2 primary key fields from other tables and a date field.

From a pragmatic point of view though sometimes creating a new surrogate column can be easier to work with than a composite one though if the PK is itself referenced in yet another table or for binding to various controls that don't handle composite primary key's well.

**Edit**

Following the update to your question I would just make the primary key composite on gallery_id, image_id. I don't see any benefit of adding a new column.

Comment: Although I don't have evidence to hand, I would imagine that using an integer surrogate key is faster for joining purposes then using a composite key. For this reason, I always create int surrogate keys on all tables.

Comment: @David - It probably is. Another thing to add into the balance!

Comment: Oh, a composite key is a new thing for me. I hadn't considered that as an option.

Answer (score 10):

In theory, if the combination of the two foreign keys (FKs) is unique in the table, or if the combination of the two FKs plus some other column is unique, then the table has a compound primary key and there is no strict need to introduce another key as a surrogate primary key.  However, it is not unusual to find that people do add an extra key.  In part, it depends on what else the data in the table with the compound primary key will used for.  If it describes something that will itself have rows from other tables associated with it, then it may make sense to introduce a simple PK.

Some software seems to require simple PKs, even though the Relational Data Model does not.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is usually "yes". The kind of table you describe is an *association table*, which stores associations. Because these records are interesting in their own right, and because you will probably want to look them up later, they should have a meaningful identity.

For instance, perhaps you have a `players` table and a `matchups` table for your tennis league. `matchups` may contain nothing more than the foreign keys of the two players that played against each other; it's an *association* between two players.

But later you may want to record other information specific to that association: the time the match occurred, the score of the game, et cetera. And, of course, as soon as you want to have more than one matchup between the same two players, you'll need to differentiate between each matchup. Thus you'll want to give each `matchup` its own identity in the form of a primary key.

---

**Update:**

```
========================
| galleries_images     |
|----------------------|
| FK | gallery_id      |
| FK | image_id        |  <----- Should I add a PK to this table?
========================
```

In your specific example, it's probably useful to have a primary key here. As soon as you need to record any metadata about the association, you'll want to have that primary key. Also, if the same image can be added to the same gallery more than once, a primary key will be necessary to differentiate between the two records.

Comment: Also, in your example, a matchup between two players may occur more than once, so simply having the two player ids as the key is not going to work either.

Comment: it would be perfectly acceptable to have a composite primary key with the 2 primary key fields from other tables and a date field though.

Answer (score 2):

If one specific image can only be associated with one single gallery, then the combinations in your galleries-images table are unique, and you may use that pair of fields as the PK.
If the galleries-images combinations can be duplicated OR
if your schema includes more tables that are goind to be childs of that galleries-images,
THEN I would suggest you do include an extra field that will be the PK.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing the locking question:

For example you could create a table
Order_image_lock (gallery ID (primary key), start_time).

Create 3 methods/sprocs:
GetLock, CheckLock, DropLock.

When you want to reorder a portfolio, you Call GetLock which inserts (gallary_id, sysdate).

If it works, you can proceed. If it fails on the PK, someone else is reordering, raise exception.

When you're ready to Reorder, call CheckLock to see if your lock is still there (you'll see why) if you have it, update the reordered values, if not go to GetLock.

When you're done, DropLock Deletes the record.

A server process can sweep the table for locks more than x minutes old. For disconnects or people who leave the screen up and head to lunch.

Add a user_id column to that table as well, so you can report back who has what locks another user may want.

This will scale far better than actually locking the rows. some dbms's have a finite amount of locks, which forces them to perform 'lock escalation' where multiple row locks are converted to a page lock until there are too many page locks and are converted to a table lock... you need to check how your RDBMs works with large lock volumes... if you plan to scale.

Answer (score 1):

You say that the foreign keys are primary keys in their own tables. That means that they are unique in those tables. It doesn't mean that they are unique in this table, however.

I have generally found that it is best to create a primary key on a database table. Sooner or later, you are going to discover that you need it, so why not include the new primary key from the start?